# is it true that $\int\limits_{x_{n}}^xf(z)dz\longrightarrow 0$

Tags: functional-analysis

If $x_{n}\longrightarrow x$ then is it true that $\int\limits_{x_{n}}^xf(z)\,\mathrm dz\longrightarrow 0$? We have that $f\in L_{2}(0,\infty)$ and takes complex values. I think that it is, but why?
In fact I want to prove that $$\frac{1}{x_{n}}\int\limits_{0}^{x_{n}}f(z)\,\mathrm dz-\frac{1}{x}\int\limits_{0}^xf(z)\,\mathrm dz\longrightarrow 0$$

Comment: The limit in the title follows from the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: By which function is dominated ?

Comment: Let $A = [x-d,x+d]$ for some positive $d < x$, and take $g = \lvert f\rvert\cdot \chi_A$, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$. Since $f\in L^2$, you have $g\in L^1$.

Comment: I think that the statement $f\in L_{2}\Longrightarrow f\in L_{1}$ it is false. Take for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: I didn't say that. I said $g\in L^1$. That follows since $f\in L^2$ and $\chi_A\in L^2$.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand. Could you explain me more thoroughly? thank you

Comment: The product of two $L^2$-functions is in $L^1$. Cauchy-Schwarz, or $\lvert ab\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\left(\lvert a\rvert^2 + \lvert b\rvert^2\right)$ show that. $\lvert f\rvert\in L^2$ by premise, and $\chi_A\in L^2$ by elementary verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\int_{x_n}^{x} f(z)  \ dz = \int_{0}^{x} f(z) \chi_{(x_n,x)} \ dz $

($ \chi_{(x_n,x)}$ is the caracteristic function of the interval $(x_n , x)$)

Clearly $\chi_{(x_n,x)} \in L^{2}(0, \infty)$. Note that $|f \chi_{(x_n,x)}| \leq 2(|f|^2 + |\chi_{(x_n,x)}|^2 )$, then it follows that $f \chi_{(x_n,x)} \in L^{1}(0.\infty)$ because $f$ and $ \chi_{(x_n,x)}$ are in $L^{2}(0.\infty)$.

Define $g_n(z) = f (z)\chi_{(x_n,x)} (z), $ Note that $g_n(z) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for all $z $ and note that $ |g_n (z)| \leq |f (z)\chi_{(x_n,x)}(z)| \leq |f(z) \chi_{(0,x)}(z)|$. Since $f \chi_{(0,x)}\in L^1(0.\infty)$(just argue with the AM-GM inequality as above) , we can apply the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{x_n}^{x} f(z)  \ dz = \displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{x} f(z) \chi_{(x_n,x)} \ dz = \int_{0}^{x}\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(z) \chi_{(x_n,x)} \ dz = \int_{0}^{x}\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} g_n(z) \ dz=0.$$

The result follows

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is good. You wrote "since $f\in L^1(0,+\infty)$, we can apply...". Are you sure that $f\in L^{1}(0,+ \infty)$? or you wanted to write $fx_{(x_{n},x)}$\in L^1(0,+\infty)$

Comment: You're welcome. I did a mistake at the end of solution. The correct is: note that    " $ |g_n (z)| \leq |f (z)\chi_{(x_n,x)}(z)| \leq |f(z) \chi_{(0,x)}|$. Since $f \chi_{(0,x)}\in L^1(0.\infty)$ ..." I will correct my error in the solution. sorry for the mistake